# how to return the image with the largest dimension

Tags: python, opencv, web-scraping, computer-vision, python-imaging-library

I have been able to filter all the image url from a page and displayed them one after the other

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


article_URL = "https://medium.com/bhavaniravi/build-your-1st-python-web-app-with-flask-b039d11f101c"
response = requests.get(article_URL)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text,'html.parser')
images = soup.find('body').find_all('img')
i = 0
image_url = []
for im in images:
    print(im)
    i+=1
    url = im.get('src')
    image_url.append(url)
    print('Downloading: ', url) 
    try:
        response = requests.get(url, stream=True)
        with open(str(i) + '.jpg', 'wb') as out_file:
            shutil.copyfileobj(response.raw, out_file)
            del response
    except:
        print('Could not download: ', url)

new = [x for x in image_url if x is not None]
for url in new:
    resp = requests.get(url, stream=True).raw
    image = np.asarray(bytearray(resp.read()), dtype="uint8")
    image = cv2.imdecode(image, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
#     height, width, channels = image.shape
    height, width, _ = image.shape
    dimension = []
    for items in height, width:
        dimension.append(items)
#     print(height, width)
    print(dimension)
```

**I want to print the image with the largest dimension from the list of url**

This is the result I have from the list which is not good enough

```
[72, 72]
[95, 96]
[13, 60]
[227, 973]
[17, 60]
[229, 771]
```

Comment: use `max()` to get the largest `width` or `height` or `width * height`

Comment: i don't understand what you do with `for items in height, width: dimension.append(items)` - why not directly `dimension.append( (height, width) )` or `dimension.append( (height*width, height, width) )` and after `for`-loop `max(dimension)`. And you have to create `dimension = []` before `for`-loop.

Comment: I don't understand why you download again the same images. If you already downloaded and saved on disk then faster should be to read from disk. And you get at once numpy array if you use `cv2.imread()`

Comment: i didn't download the image, i'm just analyzing the images straight up, i have tried max before, but the result comes out as a singular array

Comment: but first you use `response = requests.get(url, stream=True)` and `open(str(i) + '.jpg', 'wb')` to download file but later you use `resp = requests.get(url, stream=True).raw` to get the same image from server - but you already have it on disk

Comment: as I said before - you use  `dimension` in wrong way - you create `dimension = []` inside loop so you remove previous contente before you put next dimension. You have to create it only once - before loop. And you should use `dimension.append( (height, width) )` without `for items in height, width:`

Comment: ok thank you, let me try that

Comment: i have gotten the max width, you have an idea on how to get the actual image

Comment: You should keep all information in dimension ie,  `dimension.append( (height, width, url, filename) )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two problems.

1. you create `dimention = []` inside loop so it removes previous value. You have to create `dimention = []` before loop and inside loop use

   ```
   dimension.append( (width, height) )
   ```

   and after loop you can use `max(dimension)` to get pair with max `width`
2. you keep only `width, height` in `dimension` so you don't know which file has this dimention. You should keep all information

   ```
   dimension.append( (width, height, url, filename) )
   ```

---

My version.

I use dictionary `data` to keep all information

```
data.append({
                'url': url,
                'path': filename,
                'width': width,
                'height': height,
            })
```

and later I use `key` in `max()` to get item with max `width`

```
max(data, key=lambda x:x['width'])
```

but the same way I could use `x['height']` or `x['width'] * x['height']`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import shutil
import cv2

article_URL = "https://medium.com/bhavaniravi/build-your-1st-python-web-app-with-flask-b039d11f101c"

response = requests.get(article_URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
images = soup.find('body').find_all('img')

# --- loop --- 

data = []
i = 0

for img in images:
    print('HTML:', img)
    
    url = img.get('src')

    if url:  # skip `url` with `None`
        print('Downloading:', url) 
        try:
            response = requests.get(url, stream=True)

            i += 1
            url = url.rsplit('?', 1)[0]  # remove ?opt=20 after filename
            ext = url.rsplit('.', 1)[-1] # .png, .jpg, .jpeg
            filename = f'{i}.{ext}' 
            print('Filename:', filename)

            with open(filename, 'wb') as out_file:
                shutil.copyfileobj(response.raw, out_file)

            image = cv2.imread(filename)
            height, width = image.shape[:2]

            data.append({
                'url': url,
                'path': filename,
                'width': width,
                'height': height,
            })

        except Exception as ex:
            print('Could not download: ', url)
            print('Exception:', ex)

    print('---')

# --- after loop ---

print('max:', max(data, key=lambda x:x['width']))

all_sorted = sorted(data, key=lambda x:x['width'], reverse=True)

print('Top 3:', all_sorted[:3])
# or
for item in all_sorted[:3]:
    print(item['width'], item['url'])
```

---

**BTW:** to get images only with `src`

```
 .find_all('img', {'src': True})
```

Comment: apart from returning the maximum url, can we also return the top 3 url, been trying that

Comment: you can use `sorted(data, key=lambda x:x['width'], reverse=True)` instead of `max()` and then you can use `[:3]` to get top 3 urls.

Answer (score 1):

Make these changes in your code, just after you create new array:

```
images = []
for url in new:
    resp = requests.get(url, stream=True).raw
    image = np.asarray(bytearray(resp.read()), dtype="uint8")
    image = cv2.imdecode(image, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    images.append((image.shape, image))
# sort images by area (largest to smallest)
images.sort (key = lambda x: x[0][0] * x[0][1], reverse=True)
```

Largest image is at index 0 now and can be accessed by images[0][1] and it's shape can be printed using images[0][0]. You can change the lambda function to x[0][0] (sort by height) or x[0][1] (sort by width) as well.

Comment: nice, one, can you easily help to print out the actual image, instead of the pixel

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean by print out the image. You want it displayed? For that you can use plt.imshow(image) by importing matplotlib or use cv2.imshow('image',image) cv2.waitKey(0). If you want to write it to disk for that you can use cv2.imwrite().